# Leer 2 tuplas desde teclado en Haskell online

Tags: haskell

Estoy usando un compilador de Haskell online y me gustaría poder leer 2 listas de Strings desde teclado (desde el cuadro input) dos números pero tira error y no sé como corregirlo.

```
f :: [a] -> [[a]] -> [(a,a)]
f xs ys = [(x,y) | (x,zs) <- zip xs ys, y <- zs]

main = do
       xs <- getLine
       ys <- getLine
       putStrLn (show (f (read xs) (read ys)))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Las firmas de `show` y `read` son las siguientes:

```
show :: Show a => a -> String
read :: Read a => String -> a
```

El problema es que en tu programa, Haskell no puede inferir el tipo de los datos leídos, ya que estos se utilizan como argumentos de `f :: [a] -> [[a]] -> [(a,a)]`. Simplemente sabe que el primer dato es una *lista de algo*, el segundo dato es una *lista de listas de algo*, y que devuelve una *lista de tuplas de algo y algo*. Por lo tanto no sabe cómo leer tus datos con `read` y no sabe cómo mostrar luego el resultado con `show`.

Para solucionarlo debes proporcionar una anotación de tipo para la función `read`:

```
putStrLn (show (f (read xs :: [Int]) (read ys)))
```

En este caso sería suficiente con anotar uno de los datos, ya que la función `f` sólo tiene una variable de tipo, `a`, y si el primer dato es una lista de enteros, puede inferir que el segundo es una lista de listas de enteros.

No obstante, si la firma de `f` fuera esta:

```
f :: [a] -> [[b]] -> [(a,b)]
```

Tendrías que anotar el tipo de los dos datos:

```
putStrLn (show (f (read xs :: [Int]) (read ys :: [[Char]])))
```

Comment: Con lo que me enseñaste estoy preparando un  manual para Haskell online

Comment: Es una restricción de clase. Indica que una variable de tipo debe tomar un tipo que implemente esa clase. Por ejemplo, la firma de la función `sort` es `sort :: Ord a => [a] -> [a]`, donde `Ord a` indica que `a` debe ser un tipo de la clase `Ord`, es decir, un tipo que tenga una relación de orden definida. Esto tiene sentido porque no puedes ordenar una lista de datos que no sean ordenables. Te recomiendo que leas este libro, que explica desde lo más básico hasta conceptos más avanzados (te paso en concreto el capítulo de tipos y clases): http://aprendehaskell.es/content/Tipos.html

Comment: Tira error cuando lo ejecuto online diciendo a.out: Prelude.read: no parse
cuando ingreso ["A","B","C","D"] y [["B","C"],["A","C"],["A","B","D"],["C"]] en líneas separadas

Comment: Ten en cuenta que al utilizar comillas dobles, son `String` no `Char`, entonces la anotación de tipo para el primer dato es `[String]`.

Comment: Puse putStrLn (show (f (read xs :: [String]) (read ys :: [[String]])))  ¡y funcionó!